# Figure out how to add values of column a

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Created an account for this so smarter people can help me figure this out. Essentially, I have a programme that tracks order numbers in first column, and in second column, it lists the prices of items in that order. So say for example, in order 001, someone bought a mousemat for 15 dollars, a pen for 2 dollars, and a monitor for 200.
The next order, someone just bought an alarm clock for 20 dollars

| Order Number | Value USD |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 15 |
| 001 | 2 |
| 001 | 200 |
| 002 | 20 |

Essentially, I need to create a formula? that looks at the order number, and combines all the x amount of items in the value column, something like this.

| Order Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 217 |
| 002 | 20 |

Can anyone please help to try and come up with a solution that is as close to it as possible, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

I've tried a few commands with the SUMIF function, essentially wiriting SUMIF(A2:A3;A2=A3,B2:B3), but it's only spitting out zeroes

Comment: Try using `SUMIFS`.

Comment: The [SUMIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function (or the [SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function) will work for you.

Comment: I've tried the SUMIFS option, SUMIF(A2:A3;A2=A3,B2:B3), but it's only spitting out zeroes

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

**PART 1**

Sometimes the nature of how we express the condition can get confusing.  In some functions, we want the condition to be something that resolves to true or false.  For instance, `=A2=B2` will return TRUE if they are the same and FALSE if they are not.  WHich is what you tried to do in your formula.

But the SUMIF isn’t like this.  You give it a *value*, and then EXCEL, not you, determines if that value results in TRUE.  What you want is:

**PART 2**

You are using the notation A2 and A3 for both your first table and your second (results) table and this won’t work.  The results have to be somewhere else.  A different range of cells on the same sheet, or even a range of cells on a different sheet.  Let’s say your top table is in A2:B5.  And let’s assume your results table is in A10:B11.  Then in B10 you will enter this formula, and be mindful of the dollar signs:

`=SUMIF( A$2:A$5 , A10 , B$2:B$5 )`

This says “sum the values in B2:B5 in any row where the value in A2:A5 is equal to the value in A10.”

Then copy that fill that formula down or copy/paste it into B11… Automatically, the formula in B11 will be:  `=SUMIF( A$2:A$5 , A11, B$2:B$5 )`